# video editing using FFMPEG in android project

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164211/use-ffmpeg-on-android)

i want to create a android app which can merge audio images to form video i am prefering ffmpeg for that ,please guide me how can i use ffmpeg functions and libraries to do so

Answer (score 2):

the biggest challenge will be building FFMPEG. I'm not sure about Android but it is for Windows. Then you can check [this example](http://unick-soft.ru/Articles.cgi?id=20), it's in Russian but code is in `C`

Comment: thanks for ur reply i had succcessfuully compiled all the libraries and put all of them in the android project but the problem is that which native fuction should i use in the code

Comment: I would recommend to check ffmpeg.c file. It's pretty complicated example of ffmpeg API usage, but almost complete one. In short, you need to create a container (check avformat.h) for your resulting file and create two streams for audio and video track, choose codecs for them (check avcodec.h), and write data to streams sample by sample.