# Use FFMPEG on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264

Does somebody know how to use FFMPEG on Android to convert YUV420 frame to H.264?

I have ported FFMPEG work on Android with NDK, I just don't know how to use it. A source code is appreciated.

Comment: If this is a personal/non-profint/non-commercial,anything project, could you please tell us the result and how you did it, and if possible, a download link for stopping the reinvention of the wheel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. use ffmpeg api - google ffmpeg
   sample code. this requires good
   understanding of the api and which
   is very comprehnsive.
2. compile ffmpeg.c and invoke its
   main() via jni. This requires that
   you understand the command line
   parameters. It is rather cumbersome
   but works.

   You need to look out for the static vars defined in ffmpeg.c and reset them every time you invoke the main function. Also make sure you don't invoke the main in two threads simultaneously .

Comment: I am trying to do #2 that you stated above. I have asked this question already and have not gotten any useful answers and that is why I am resorting to asking it here. Could you please give me some information on how to call ffmpeg.c through JNI. I am just getting all kinds of compiling errors when I add it to the Android.mk file.

Comment: would be happy to help, but please add your compilation errors. probably it would be better to do that in a new question.

Comment: Thank you! Any help is much appreciated! I created my own question with a some details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412722/compile-ffmpeg-c-and-call-its-main-via-jni)