# Use FFMPEG on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164211/use-ffmpeg-on-android)

I have all the required `.so` file for ffmpeg but I don't know how to use it with android application.

Any help or tutorial or sample app link will do a lot for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669220/ndk-how-to-use-a-generated-so-library-in-another-project) may help you

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically  you need to write your own Android.mk and Application.mk files such a way that your Android application can handle the generated so files and wrap them.

You need to check the Android-NDK [documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

You can also use the [Bambuser's](http://bambuser.com/opensource) ffmpeg port for Android.