# how to use ffmpeg to android for getting frame of video file in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164211/use-ffmpeg-on-android)

I am working an project which are used to getting video frame for editing and save as same location of frame.

I am search a lot but result is , should be use ffmpeg library for getting frame.

Please give me a simple and steps by steps example

Comment: Did you get the answer ?? I am working on that and i am stuck  in to it.
can you please share your code?

Answer (score 2):

In this [blog](http://www.roman10.net/category/android-tutorial/ffmpeg-on-android) you can find some examples to step by step port ffmpeg to android. After you have just installed, you can save frames or use antoher ffmpeg functions.