# How to use ffmpeg project in android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164211/use-ffmpeg-on-android)

How can i use ffmpeg in android. I want to edit frame of video file and again save as same position same as they extract?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2645041/741249 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/4725773/741249, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5164211/741249