# Convert a video to audio on an android device (Java)

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

My problem is very basic, yet I find it incredibly hard to find a solution.

I have made an android app which downloads videos from a server and is then supposed to convert them into mp3, because it's for music downloads. The problem now is that I can't really find a **lightweight** way of converting the videos.

I have looked into a suitable ffmpeg library/wrapper already, but couldn't find a simple solution to use on the android. I'm already using ffmpeg on my windows machine, but it is console-based.

All I need to do is convert mp4 into mp3 but somehow there doesn't seem to by any simple solution to find, also I'd rather not use an external web service because I can't rely on a website to always function, while my app should.

I hope I've made myself clear, and thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Are you downloading a very big video file just to get the audio from it? Why not just download just the audio instead? Maybe it's not your website?

Comment: *"All I need to do is convert mp4 into mp3.."*  You make it sound like stripping audio from a video file on a phone or tablet (or desktop or server) is trivial.

Comment: It is indeed not my website, and I do not have much knowledge on audio/video codecs and the conversion between them. Hence my question

Comment: *"It is indeed not my website"*  YouTube perhaps?  @Pulsar made a good call on that one.  The easiest solution is to find out what API the site supports for serving an MP3.

Comment: It is not Youtube. It is quite similar though, just without the playback function. Basically it's just a big server with a lot of music videos. For as far as I know there's no possibility to just download MP3. If there is with Youtube I might have to take a look at that instead, it's the same concept after all

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg in your application code to achieve this. Check this question for some directions: [Use FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164211/use-ffmpeg-on-android)