# How to get video frames from mp4 video using ffmpeg in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have successfully compiled and build ffmpeg library in android after 3,4 days research work.
Now I want to grab frames from video. But I don't know which ffmpeg method with command to be called from java class to grab the all frames. Any one have idea about it? or I want to overlay 2 videos. Is there any direct method available in ffmpeg to merge two videos one over another? If yes, how to call it from java class?

Comment: I have looked all your questions you should accept some more even if not all got answers 2 of 25 is quiet bad ratio. That questions I read had all a little quality problems: You need to add what you have tried and where you have failed. However I know that the topic FFMPEG is very complicated. How ever I think this is a good question even if it is too localizated and also not constructive. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

compile `ffmpeg.c` and invoke its `main()` via jni.

For more details see how to [Use FFMPEG on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164211/use-ffmpeg-on-android/5167375#5167375) .

Also [refer](https://github.com/churnlabs/android-ffmpeg-sample) this github project. And [this](http://www.quack-ware.com/2011/include-ffmpeg-in-android-and-grab-a-frame-from-a-3gp-video/) tutorial too will help you.

I hope this will help you.