# Android Video File Processing and re display = performance issue

Tags: android, file, image-processing, android-mediaplayer

I am working on a project to read a video file from sdcard then process frames and re diplay as a video in real time. So far I didn't manage to come up with a solution for directly extract frames from the `MediaPlayer` like `MediaPlayer.getCurrentFrame();`. `MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()` is super slow, difficult to get a descent frame rate.

The only thing I have right now is using a `TextureView` surface with `MediaPlayer`. Here I start the `MediaPlayer` and in real time read the bitmap form `TextureView` as`TextureView.getBitMap()`, then process `BitMap` and display it on another `ImageView`. Here this gives me a a descent frame rate.

The problem here is `TextureView` has to be in the xml layout and should visible, Which I do not want.

Can some one please shed some light here? Is it possible to somehow hide the `TextureView` which is attaching to the `MediaPlayer`, without fake hiding like using RelativeLayouts :). iOS has a solution for this which is `AVPLAyerItemVideoOutput`, I need something like that with android.

Or any other work around to extract frames from video file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For video processing ...... you can use the FFMPEG Library for getting frames of videos but for that you have the knowledge of android native integration.

I hope this will help you.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890072/how-to-get-video-frames-from-mp4-video-using-ffmpeg-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I will try the FFMPEG. But it would be really nice if sdk could support this. Because IOS has this feature. Before submitting a feature request does any one has an idea on how to solve this. Extract  frames from a video file(mp4) seamlessly in android mediaplayer?